# ios singleton http request

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton

I have an app with a few viewcontrollers.
One of the view controllers (not the first screen) will need to show data fetched from server.
This data will be the same during the lifecycle, which means: when the user logs in into the app, I can fetch the data from the server (would be the home screen in the app). Then when the user goes to the view controller that will display the data, then the data can be the same all the time.

One (bad?) solution is that each time the user goes to the page with the data I make an htt request to get the data.
Another (better?)solution is singleton? Is that correct?
If yes:
The data can be fetched by instantiating the singleton after login? And then all the times the user goes to the page with the data it will get the data from the singleton? Is that a good approach?

Comment: If you need to have the data persisted for the next launch use the DB(Core data) to save the data. 

Else if its a one time call then you can use the singleton approach to save and fetch the data each time. Call service only if there is a need to update the data and not frequently.

Comment: why dont you use a user default or some database, if your data is not going to updated. it will be available for whole application.

Comment: Thing is that the data from database (on the server) can change very seldom, maybe once a month. And even if it changes while the user is logged in there is no really need to tell the user about that, i.e. its ok he still sees the data fetched when he logged in. So given this description, it is a good idea to make to call to the server only once in the lifecycle of a user session? I mean: the user logs in into the app. First time he goes to the screen with that data, the singleton makes the server request. After that, the data is taken from singleton without doing a real call to the server.

Comment: And this would happen all the time the user is using this "sessioN" of the app. Next time it starts the app the singleton will begin from scratch again. Am I thinking the right way? Thanks.